# Random Phantom Sound On Computer - Could it be from ham radio?

Tags: rfi

For the past few months, I've been experiencing an odd random sound on my new computer (as well as 2 other PCs I've tested). It seems to occur only when the internet is connected. I have changed ISPs, bought a new router, and changed service from DSL to cable - but the exact sound continues. I've painstakingly ruled out all hardware or Windows causes.

I've recorded the sound. Here's the link: https://soundcloud.com/finvarra/nuc-sound-2

I realize I'm grasping at straws, but... does anyone recognize this sound - and could it possibly be caused by a ham radio in the neighborhood? Thanks...

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com! Please consider taking [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) to get the most from the site.

Comment: Ditto with @Mike's suggestion you take the tour.  For instance, you will learn that the question should pose a specific goal, then show your attempts to solve it, then can come your hypothesis of why you haven't yet achieved it, (based on photos of your neighbor's huge ham radio antenna, perhaps), then pose a specific question (like should I knock on his door and ask him for help?).  Unless it is in accordance with the guidelines it will likely be closed as being Too Broad, or Unclear What You Are Asking, or maybe even Off-Topic.  Meanwhile, you are welcome here.

Comment: Does it occur if you boot the computer into Linux on a live CD? What about if you enter the BIOS screen and just wait there, or somehow jam the boot process? What about with the computer suspended or off? These might help you narrow down the source.

Comment: You stated that "It *seems* to occur only when the internet is connected". Have you absolutely determined that the sound **never** occurs when your LAN cable is unplugged?

Comment: Michael, may I suggest that you ask this question again in [Super User](https://superuser.com/), which is computer-related. If you do that, you might mention that you asked it on https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/random-phantom-sound-on-computer-could-it-be-from-ham-radio and so far, no one has solved it. (This is assuming you're running Windows and not [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [other Linux distro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a noise that would be made from a program running in the background. My first thought was Discord.

Diagnosing external sounds is easily done by muting the computer at the OS level, if the sound still continues, it is external to the PC.

See what programs are running on both of the affected PC's, chances are they are running in the background and creating the noise.

Answer (score 0):

**It is almost certainly not caused by amateur radio or CB.**

EDIT: I've seen cell phones sitting next to computer speakers that caused odd noises to come from the speakers. It took us a long time to figure that one out.

Are there any CB, amateur, or other antennas nearby? The only thing that I can think of that would be related to radio is a sound effect device that some CBers put on their radio. It makes a brief sound at the beginning of every transmission. And there's also *roger beep* that occurs at the end. Both are usually far louder than the voice, and can drive the radio into saturation and generate harmonics.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any feasible way that sound would be due to a radio transmission of any kind. Although *strong* RF fields can interfere with audio electronics, they would not sound like that. Try setting a cell phone on some cheap computer speakers, for example. Anything digital (most things in modern times) would sound like noise. For AM stations you might hear the music, voice, or whatever's being transmitted, but it's usually garbled. I doubt any station is transmitting the "beep-boop" you are hearing and nothing else.

A more likely explanation is some software or some feature on your computer you don't realize you have.

Comment: Crossing my fingers but... I may have found the culprit. If so, it was a combo of Wireshark and blind luck. Noticed instances of Sonos packets popping up around the time of the sound incidents, remembered that the Sonos controller was the *only* piece of hardware that had touched all 3 computers and hadn't been replaced or swapped out. Recently, it had been disconnnecting from the network sometimes (I never thought of it b/c it's in another room), but I happened to have another one handy. Since replacing it, I've heard no sounds. 2 days in.